# specify @return type in phpdoc based on input parameter value

Tags: php, phpdoc

Does anyone know any way to specify `@return` type based on the input parameter?

My project has a lot of method calls such as

`...->getComponent('name')->someMethod()`

where `getComponent` is a service locator and IDE doesn't understand which value it returns.

Comment: Not to my knowledge (and probably it differs by IDE). How many services do you have, and how dynamic are they? Is just defining `getComponentWhateverName()` not an option?

Answer (score 2):

For the [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/) IDE, you can create one or more files called `.phpstorm.meta.php` in your project. Here is an example content of such a file:

```php
<?php

namespace PHPSTORM_META {

    override(\Factory::getComponent(), map([
        "name" => \some\namespace\Name::class,
        "exception" => \Exception::class,
    ]));

}
```

You can find the documentation here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#map

I recommend committing this file to make auto-completion available to other PhpStorm users.

Answer (score 1):

The only way would be to have `getComponent()`'s `@return` tag actually list out all possible data types that could return.  This kind of dynamic, loose typing behavior that PHP allows for is not conducive to such static resolution as done by an IDE autocomplete.  It has always been a tough case to try to document, because your API doc is just as "static" as the "object tree" that an IDE has to construct in order to provide autocompletion.

If IDE autocompletion is urgent enough to warrant adjusting the code to make it happen, then aside from my earlier

`@return ClassOne|ClassTwo|...|ClassInfinitum` option,

you could split the two calls rather than chaining them, and use an `@var` "local docblock" that **some** IDEs know how to recognize:

```
// this litte docblock establishes the data type for the local variable $nameComponent
// note however that some IDEs want "datatype varname", 
// some want "varname datatype",
// and some don't recognize the docblock at all
/** @var \NameClass $myComponent */
$nameComponent = $service->getComponent('name');
```

```
// here, the known methods of NameClass should pop up after typing ->
$nameComponent->
```